# How do we show that for massless fermions, Helcity and Chirality align?

Tags: fermions, spinors, chirality, helicity

The Helicity operator of a representation of the Lorentz group is given by $$h = \varepsilon_{ijk}S^{jk}\frac{P^i}{|P|}$$ where $S^{\mu\nu}$ are the generators of the Lorentz group.

In the $(\frac{1}{2},0)\oplus(0,\frac{1}{2})$ rep, for a massless Dirac spinor with momentum purely in the $+z$ direction, the helicity operator becomes:

$$h=\frac{1}{2}\left(\begin{array}{ll}
\sigma_z & 0 \\
0 & \sigma_z
\end{array}\right)$$
Which has splits our space of spinors into two eigen-subspaces:
$$
\psi = \psi_+ + \psi_- \quad \rightarrow \quad \psi_+ = \left(\begin{array}{l}
a \\
0 \\
b \\
0 \\
\end{array}\right), \quad \psi_- = \left(\begin{array}{l}
0 \\
c \\
0 \\
d \\
\end{array}\right)$$

We also have the Chirality operator $\gamma^5$, which when working in the Chiral basis, is also diagonal:
$$\gamma^5=\left(\begin{array}{ll}
-I_2 & 0 \\
0 & I_2
\end{array}\right)$$
Which again splits our space of spinors into $2$ eigen-subspaces
$$
\psi = \psi_L + \psi_R \quad \rightarrow \quad \psi_L = \left(\begin{array}{l}
a \\
c \\
0 \\
0 \\
\end{array}\right), \quad \psi_R = \left(\begin{array}{l}
0 \\
0 \\
b \\
d \\
\end{array}\right)$$
Clearly if we only allow cases when $c = b = 0$ then these operators are the same up on this subspace (up to a constant), but that doesn't seem to necessarily be the case.

What am I missing that allows us to say that for massless fermions, Helicity and Chirality are the same?

Answer (score 1):

You need an input from  dynamics. The  Weyl hamiltonan for a right-handed (positive chirality) fermion is
$$
H= {\boldsymbol \sigma}\cdot {\bf p}
$$
so with ${\bf p}=(0,0,p)$ positive energy eigenstates have their spin a +1 eigenstate of $\sigma_z$, i.e their spin is
parallel to  the momentum (positive helicity). Negative energy  correspond to antiparticles and have negative helicity.

Answer (score 1):

Mike Stone stirred my thought process and made me realize that physical spinors must obey the (massless) Dirac equation. For the specific set-up at hand this leads to the conditions that:
$$
\begin{split}
\sigma_z\>\psi_L &= I_2 \>\psi_L \\
\sigma_z\>\psi_R &= -I_2 \>\psi_R 
\end{split}
$$
Where I'm abusing the notation to make $\psi_{L/R}$ represent the $2$-component Weyl spinors. This forces the very condition $c=b=0$ in order for the eigen-spaces of the operators on physical spinors to coincide.